# How two process can log in single file with Python? / Logging to a single file from multiple processes

Tags: python, logging, process, error-logging

I have requirement to generate new log for each day in my application And i am having two process in application. So i am facing issue as 1 process is not able to write into new day log and another is writing.

For more clarification here is what i am doing..

```py
import logging
import os, sys
import os.path
import datetime
from threading import Thread
import time

firstTime = "false"


def initialize_logger(fileName):

    global firstTime
    try:
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        output_dir = os.getcwd()
        if firstTime == "true":
            for handler in logger.handlers[:]:  # get rid of existing old handlers                
                logger.removeHandler(handler)
        # create debug file handler and set level to debug
        try:
            handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(output_dir, fileName), "w")
        except:
            print("problem to create log")

        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-30s) %(asctime)s %(message)s ")
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        firstTime = "true"
    except Exception as ex:
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred at {1}. Arguments:\n{2!r}"
        message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, tb.tb_lineno, ex.args)
        logging.error(message)


def daily_log(dummyStr):
    global firstTime

    try:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()        
        log_day = now.day
        initialize_logger("Log_start.log")
        while True:
            currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().day
            time.sleep(60)

            if currentDate != log_day:  # New day started              
                initialize_logger("Log_continue.log")

    except Exception as ex:
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred at {1}. Arguments:\n{2!r}"
        message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, tb.tb_lineno, ex.args)
        logging.error(message)


logThread = Thread(target=daily_log, name="dailyLogThread", args=("dummy",))

logThread.start()
```

If anyone can help me with understanding this issue and what other alternative i can take to get all logs in new day file..

Your suggestion will be very helpful!!

Comment: Most of the code is irrelevant for the question. For example what is the reason for using threads?

Comment: Sorry! Ignore the daily_log as thread call, consider it as function call. I have written this code to _.py file which i am importing to other modules. But on my main process i have one more process call. so when new day starts, only main process logs are written to file and not the another one.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, *normally opened*(*) files can only be accessed by one single process. And on Unix-like system, having more than one thread/process writing to a same file without special synchronization can lead to mixed output (said differently unreadable garbage...).

That means that you cannot simply use `FileHandlers` for 2 processes to log to the same file.

What can be done:

1. use the system logging interfaces (`SysLogHandler` or `NTEventLogHandler`) because they expect to be used by many processes. `syslog` can natively use a sequential file for selected sources, and NTEventLog can export selected events
2. use a *relay*. For example the main processes could use a `DatagramHandler` and a relay process *listens* on the socket, read the packets, format them back into `LogRecord` with `makeLogRecord` and finaly write them to the `FileHandler`.

---

(*) Of course the API allows special modes to allow concurrent accesses to a file, but  this cannot be (easily) done from Python

Comment: [I am new to the coding, So sorry for silly query once again] I have doubt, on the first day of running application both process logs are getting written to file but as new day starts only main process logs getting written and other process is still writing to old day log.. So is any mistake I am doing with logger object.